# Angular component specific styles to use tailwind @apply function

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

Most of the tutorials and articles are using approach to import tailwind dependencies in styles.scss

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

And then write custom styles with @apply function in custom-components.css or some separate file in global level.

But what if I want to use @apply function with tailwind in my component scoped styles? Is that possible?

Currently either my f.x. custom-component.css is polluted with different component styles, or component html is polluted with many classes.

BR

Comment: Same question here !

Answer (score 0):

I used [@ngneat/tailwind](https://github.com/ngneat/tailwind) to add tailwindcss to my angular project and I could use `@apply` in my scss file of component.

However, it seems like nesting is not working all the time for me and, most important, `dark` variants is not working as well ([here is the explanation](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss.com/pull/759)).

Tailwind's documentation about components is to avoid using custom classes and just keep tailwind classes in the html if it's complex and only used in one component.